# Why is there error message when use cuda-memcheck, but there is not error when directly run the program

Tags: c++, cuda

My code is like this:

```
template<typename scalar_t>
__global__ void compute_square(const int num, const scalar_t* data, scalar_t* res, float* time) {
    clock_t start = clock();
    const int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    int stride = blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
    for (int i{tid}; i < num; i+=stride) {
        res[i] = data[i] * data[i];
    }

    clock_t finish = clock();
    time[tid] = (float)(finish - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
}


template<typename scalar_t>
__global__ void compute_sum(const int num, const scalar_t* data, scalar_t* sum) {
    const int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    extern __shared__ scalar_t shared[]; // dynamic allocated
    shared[threadIdx.x] = 0; // assign 0 to the aligned memory
    __syncthreads();
    if (tid < num) {
        shared[threadIdx.x] = data[tid];
    }
    __syncthreads();

    for (int s=1; s < blockDim.x; s*=2) {
        int idx = 2 * s * threadIdx.x;
        if (idx < blockDim.x) {
            shared[idx] += shared[idx + s];
        }
        __syncthreads();
    }

    if (threadIdx.x == 1) { // must be one thread, or will be added many times
        atomicAdd(sum, shared[0]);
    }
}
void test_cuda_sync() {
    cout << "test sync" << endl;
    int len{1000};
    vector<float> data(len);
    vector<float> res(len); 
    vector<float> time(len);
    float sum{0};
    std::iota(data.begin(), data.end(), 0);

    // allocate memory
    float *dev_data{nullptr}, *dev_res{nullptr}, *dev_time{nullptr};
    float *dev_sum{nullptr};
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_data, sizeof(float) * len);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_res, sizeof(float) * len);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_time, sizeof(float) * len);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_sum, sizeof(float));

    // copy data to device
    cudaMemcpy(dev_data, data.data(), sizeof(float) * len, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(dev_sum, &sum, sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    // execute kernel function
    dim3 block(512);
    dim3 grid(std::min(4096, (int)std::ceil(len / 512.))); 
    compute_square<float><<<grid, block, 0>>>(len, dev_data, dev_res, dev_time);
    compute_sum<float><<<grid, block, 4096>>>(len, dev_data, dev_sum);

    // copy results back to host
    cudaMemcpy(&res[0], dev_res, sizeof(int) * len, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaMemcpy(&time[0], dev_time, sizeof(float) * len, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaMemcpy(&sum, dev_sum, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    vector<int> tmp_cpu(len);

    // free allocated memory
    cudaFree(dev_data);
    cudaFree(dev_res);
    cudaFree(dev_time);
    cudaFree(dev_sum);

    // check results
    cout << "cuda reduce sum is: \n";
    cout << sum << endl;
    sum = 0;
    for (auto &el : data)
        sum += el;
    cout << "cpu sum is: \n";
    cout << sum << endl;

    for (int i{0}; i < 10; ++i) {
        cout << res[i] << ", ";
    } cout << endl;
    cout << (float)time[0] << endl;

}
```

The problem is that: when I compile it and run the compiled executable `main` with `./main`, there is not error, and the output result is correct, however, when I run with `cuda-memcheck`, there are a lot of error messages: `cuda-memcheck ./main`, the error messages are:

```
=========
========= Invalid __global__ write of size 4
=========     at 0x000001e0 in void compute_square<float>(int, float const *, float*, float*)
=========     by thread (488,0,0) in block (1,0,0)
=========     Address 0x7fd2a6202fa0 is out of bounds
=========     Device Frame:void compute_square<float>(int, float const *, float*, float*) (void compute_square<float>(int, float const *, float*, float*) : 0x1e0)
=========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at kernel launch time
=========     Host Frame:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1 (cuLaunchKernel + 0x2fe) [0x282a4e]
=========     Host Frame:./main [0x11e09]
=========     Host Frame:./main [0x11e97]
=========     Host Frame:./main [0x481e5]
=========     Host Frame:./main [0x3e10]
=========     Host Frame:./main (_Z14test_cuda_syncv + 0x211) [0x4691]
=========     Host Frame:./main (main + 0x12) [0x3b52]
=========     Host Frame:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main + 0xf0) [0x20830]
=========     Host Frame:./main (_start + 0x29) [0x3c39]
=========
```

What is the problem with my code please, and why there is not problem when I run the program, but there are many error messages when I run with cuda-memcheck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array is of size 1000, right? Check indexes in memcheck output -

```
=========     by thread (488,0,0) in block (1,0,0)
```

and how you calculate index in `compute_square`

```
    const int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
```

488 + 1 * 512 is 1000, which is first index out of bounds.

Comment: Hi, I do not thinks this would be a problem, since there is this line: `for (int i{tid}; i < num; i+=stride)` which will make thread out of bound safe. The 488th thread of block1 will not enter this loop and will not be an index. Why is there still errors here please?

Comment: @coincheung So make sure you are checking right compilation. Please add debug symbols (by -g3 and -O0) if they are not present, we will see precisely line in which this access is made.

Comment: After looking carefully, I found the exact place where the error comes from. But I did not see the line from the error message after adding `-g3 and -O0` to the compile option. Do I need to run `cuda-memcheck ./main` to see from the error message which line the error comes from ?

Comment: @coincheung Yes, I think output should be more verbose in `cuda-memcheck ./main` after compiling it with full debug (`-g3 -O0`).

Comment: @coincheung I found this in docs ` The output displayed by the CUDA-MEMCHECK tools is more useful with some extra compiler flags. The -G option to nvcc forces the compiler to generate debug information for the CUDA application. To generate line number information for applications without affecting the optimization level of the output, the -lineinfo option to nvcc can be used. The CUDA-MEMCHECK tools fully support both of these options and can display source attribution of errors for applications compiled with line information. ` Please add -lineinfo option to clang

Comment: @coincheung https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-memcheck/index.html#compilation-options. `nvcc -Xcompiler -rdynamic -lineinfo  -o out in.cu` This is sample line